# Delete and reinstall a VM in a Xen server

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

How do I completely delete an old VM in a Xen host?

I want to reinstall the vm new from scratch with

```
xen-create-image --hostname=something --size=8Gb --swap=2Gb --memory=1Gb --ip=10.77.77.105 --dist=jessie
```

I already shut it down with

```
xl destroy something
```

but I want to get free of the disk-space and create the whole virtual-mashine new. If I just try to recreate it now with the `xen-create-image` command, I get an error

```
Configuration file already exists; /etc/xen/something.cfg
```

Comment: `rm /etc/xen/something.cfg`? To overwrite the last disks with the same name, I think just using `-f`works too.

Comment: Which version of XenServer are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just recreate with with the option `--force` (`-f` is ambigious):

```
xen-create-image --force --hostname=something --size=8Gb --swap=2Gb --memory=1Gb --ip=10.77.77.105 --dist=jessie
```

Answer (score 2):

To list the VMs on the server:

```
xe vm-list
```

To remove, you first need to shut it down then destroy it.

```
xe vm-shutdown uuid=<uuid-of-vm>
xe vm-destroy uuid=<uuid-of-vm>
```

To destroy storage repository (SR):

```
xe sr-list
xe pbd-unplug uuid=<uuid-of-pbd>
xe sr-forget uuid=<uuid-of-sr>
```

To remove virtual disks (VDI):

```
xe vdi-destroy uuid=<uuid-of-vdi>
```